# xsetwacom settings lost after switching to another computer with kvm switch. Ubuntu 22.04

Tags: 22.04, wacom

I have a few Wacom settings that I have loading at startup, but they are lost when I switch off my monitor to use another input and then come back. I have been trying to figure out some way to trigger the script again at that point. If I could find some way to make these settings permanent I would be so happy. Thanks!

```
xsetwacom --set "Wacom Intuos S 2 Pen stylus"  Button 2 "pan"
xsetwacom --set "Wacom Intuos S 2 Pen stylus" "PanScrollThreshold" 30
xsetwacom --set "Wacom Intuos S 2 Pen stylus" Area 0 0 15200 6000
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After trying every solution for a week and a half, I finally got this working through a udev rule. I needed to set the DISPLAY and XAUTORITY, and I was using the wrong settings for those initially. I also needed to call the script through an intermediary script for some reason.

/etc/udev/rules.d/99-wacom.rules

```
ACTION=="add" SUBSYSTEM=="usb", ENV{ID_VENDOR_ID}=="056a", ENV{ID_MODEL_ID}=="033b", RUN+="/usr/local/bin/wacomconfig.sh"
```

/usr/local/bin/wacomconfig.sh (set to chmod +x)

```
#!/bin/bash

/usr/local/bin/wacom.sh &
```

/usr/local/bin/wacom.sh (set to chmod +x)

```
#!/bin/bash
export XAUTHORITY=/run/user/501/gdm/Xauthority
export DISPLAY=:1

sleep 1
xsetwacom --set "Wacom Intuos S 2 Pen stylus"  Button 2 "pan"
xsetwacom --set "Wacom Intuos S 2 Pen stylus" "PanScrollThreshold" 30
xsetwacom --set "Wacom Intuos S 2 Pen stylus" Area 0 0 15200 6000
```

And I found out what my DISPLAY and XAUTHORITY were using these:

```
ps -u $(id -u) -o pid= |
  xargs -I{} cat /proc/{}/environ 2>/dev/null |
  tr '\0' '\n' |
  grep -m1 '^XAUTHORITY='

ps -u $(id -u) -o pid= |
  xargs -I{} cat /proc/{}/environ 2>/dev/null |
  tr '\0' '\n' |
  grep -m1 '^DISPLAY='
```

And found out my ID_VENDOR_ID and ID_MODEL_ID using

```
lsusb
```